# Compile same source code into .NET 2.0 and .NET 4.0 c#

Tags: c#, .net

I have an application that runs on Windows XP, 7 and 8. I don't want the user to install the .NET framework if not available, so I am compiling it in 2.0 for Windows XP and 7 and in 4.0 for Windows 8.

At the moment I am maintaining two sets of same code one developed in 2.0 and the other in 4.0.

Is there any way that I maintain only one set of code and compile it into both frameworks easily?

There are also some dependencies like agsxmpp.dll and SQLLite.dll

Comment: Why not just compile for .net2.0? It will work in both machines which have 2.0 or 4.0. Maintaining two versions is a pain..

Comment: You'll need to use an app.config file with the `<supportedRuntime>` element to convince the CLR that you have tested your app to work properly on v4.0

Comment: @SriramSakthivel Windows 8 do not have .NET 2.0 and 4.0 also doesn't support 2.0 apps.

Comment: @HansPassant Can you please share any example or article regarding this. or explain a bit more. Thank you.

Comment: [Installing the .NET Framework 3.5 on Windows 8 or 8.1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh506443(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: *I don't want the user to install the .NET framework if not available* Why so? Ok, WIndows XP don't have any .net framework installed by default. So what your application has to do in this scenario?

Comment: OK lets rule out XP. Let's talk about 7 and 8.
@BlackFrog I don't want user to install Framework on their Windows.

Comment: I am with @SriramSakthivel, your assumption about .NET 4 not being able to run .NET 2 compile code is rubbish.

Comment: In addition to what @leppie and others have said here; you can easily enable 3.5 on 8/8.1, and 3.5 basically *is* 2.0.

Comment: @leppie With all due respect, please compile a code on 2.0 and try to run it on 4.0

Comment: @SyedRizwanAli: I do all the time... IronScheme does it. The main DLL is compiled for .NET 2, only the executable is targetted differently. I can run the same main DLL on ASP.NET for .NET 2 or 4, both x86 and x64 (and Mono while we at it) without issues. If you want to try yourself: http://build.ironscheme.net/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you really want to do this, you create one solution file with two projects.  One of your project becomes the master in the sense that you do all editing and debugging in that project.  And the other project just link to same files but the target framework is different.

In my example, I set the target framework of the master project to 2.0.  This way I know everything I write there will compile.

[image: Sample Solution with Two Projects].

Then every time I add files to the second project (Target framework 4) I add them as a linked item. [image: Add as Link].

The trick here is to keep the default namespace the same. [image: Namespace Sample]

Comment: PERFECT.. Love you for this :)